# Add the Author Profile Picture on WebContent

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have a Liferay WebContent that is based on a Structure and Template. I want to display the Author picture (from Liferay UserProfile) as part of the Template.

Is there a way to access that Information with Velocity?

I found this variable:

`$reserved-article-author-id`

However, is there an easy way to get the Picture using the AuthorID?

In the profile page, pictures are displayed this way:

The imgid is not the same as the userid. Is there an easy way to get the imgid from the userid?

Liferay Version is 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on 6.1:

```
#set ($userLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#set ($user = $userLocalService.fetchUserById($getterUtil.getLong($reserved-article-author-id.data)))
#set ($profilePicUrl = $request.theme-display.path-image + "/user_")
#if ($user.isFemale())
  #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "female")
#else
  #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "male")
#end

#set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "_portrait?img_id=")
#set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + $user.getPortraitId())

<img src="$profilePicUrl" />
```

Note that you must have `journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=` in your `portal-ext.properties` file, to allow access to `$serviceLocator`

Comment: Hi, I tried but it is not working... I am using this inside a Template that is associated with a structure. Even after adding the serviceLocator variable to the portal-ext.properties (with the =serviceLocator) and making sure the right file is loaded. If I print out $serviceLocator, $serviceLocator is the output...

Comment: Never mind, your exact version was fine, but some documentation I found tried to send me the other way with the =serviceLocator... Now it should work...

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answer, helped me out!

just a little thing

```
#set ($profilePicUrl = $request.theme-display.path-image + "/user_")
```

didnt work for me in liferay 6.2 GA2, it seems **$request.theme-display.path-image** doesnt work in the new version

but i solved like this:

```
#set ($profilePicUrl = "$theme_display.getPathImage()" + "/user_")
```

hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Thanks... At the end, I also changed some details in the implementation to match my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This work on 6.2:

Try this:

```
#set ($journalArticleLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService"))
#set ($jaId = $getterUtil.getString($reserved-article-id.data))
#set ($ja = $journalArticleLocalService.getArticle($getterUtil.getLong($groupId),$jaId))

#set ($userLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#set ($usuario = $userLocalService.getUserById($getterUtil.getLong($ja.getUserId())))
#set ($tD = $request.get("theme-display")) #set ($DigesterUtil = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.DigesterUtil"))
#set ($DigesterUtil = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.DigesterUtil"))


        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "_portrait?img_id=")
        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + $usuario.getPortraitId())


        #set ($profilePicUrl = $tD.get("path-image") + "/user_")
        #if ($usuario.isFemale())
          #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "female")
        #else
          #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "male")
        #end

        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "_portrait?img_id=")
        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + $usuario.getPortraitId())

        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + "&img_id_token=")
        #set ($profilePicUrl = $profilePicUrl + $httpUtil.encodeURL($DigesterUtil.digest($usuario.getUuid())))

        <div class="img_user">          
            <img src="$profilePicUrl"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is smaller version for Liferay 6.2:

```html
#set($userConstants = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.model.UserConstants"))

#set($portraitUrl = $userConstants.getPortraitURL($request.theme-display.path-image, $user.male, $user.portraitId, $user.userUuid))
```

Regards,
Martin